# Setting Xaml Property for XmlDataProvider with ClickOnce

Tags: wpf, xaml, clickonce

I have a WPF app that presents items in a list box based on content of an xml file. The xaml is currently like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <XmlDataProvider Source="DbPaths.xml"
                     XPath="Databases/Database"></XmlDataProvider>
</Window.DataContext>
```

This works fine when F5 debugging. My problem is, when the app is run from a ClickOnce installation, dbpaths.xml is never found because it lives in the data directory rather than the exe's directory.

In the code-behind (this app doesn't use mvvm), I could set a property for the path to the file like this:

```
public string DbPath { get; set; }
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
    DbPath = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + @"\DbPaths.xml";
}
else
{
    DbPath = "DbPaths.xml";
}
```

My problem is, I don't know how to assign the DbPath class property to the Source attribute of the  element at runtime?

Comment: In code behind you can just cast this.DataContext to XmlDataProvider and then set the Source property.  I think though, I would be inclined to just new up a XmlDataProvider and set the datacontext to that. There's only 2 properties on the thing, I wouldn't over think it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the `XmlDataProvider` programmatically in the constructor of the window instead of creating it in your XAML markup:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    XmlDataProvider provider = new XmlDataProvider()
    {
        XPath = "Databases/Database"
    };
    provider.Source = ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed ?
        ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory + @"\DbPaths.xml" : "DbPaths.xml";

    DataContext = provider;
}
```

This is the general solution whenever you want to do something dynamic that a markup language like XAML doesn't support.